# Migrate DevOps projects to new tenant

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We are migrating to a new Azure\Office 365 tenant due to a name change.  We also subscribe to DevOps through Azure.  Is there a way to reconfigure authentication so it looks at our new Azure AD for authentication?  Or do we need to figure out how to migrate projects?  THanks

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?